# Move the app from mysql phpmyadmin into database workbech

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, workbench

[image]

Hey, I am trying to move the app from MySQL PHPMyAdmin into a database workbench to make it public. but I get this error

this my code :

```
public function getUserGroupByUserId($user_id) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_group 
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = user_group.group_id 
    WHERE user_group.user_id = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_id));
    $result = $query->row_array();

    return $result;

}
```

}

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G `GROUPS (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)`

Comment: Thank you! @CBroe